# How do I allow emoji's without risking XSS <:out>

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, xss

Code example:

```
<c:out value="${slide.textContent}"/>
```

Output example: `' <script> alert("Hello! I am an alert box!")</script> &#128515; '`

So what I am trying to do is that the last part of the example is a normal emoji and I want it to be displayed. But at the same time I want it to be save for XSS. So setting escapeXml to false is not the way to do it. what is a good way to solve this problem or are there other ways to let this work out?

Recommendation are more than welcome.

edit: the first part of the example  `<script>` should **stay as text**. I might understand the confusion so that's why I'm mention it.

Kind of solution:

I did solve it by calling the text with Javascript & than placing it again

```
   function myFunction() {
  var inputText = document.getElementById("myList").textContent;
  var outputText = inputText.replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;");
  document.getElementById("myList").innerHTML = outputText;}
```

But I am still wondering what the real solution is. It seems that a lot of companies replace the Emoji with a image. Wondering why there is no libary for something like that.

Comment: You could try to try to escape the html characters by yourself without escaping `&`. But the users could also directly enter the emojis or you could explicitely replace the emoji escape sequences with the actual emojis before escaping with `c:out`